Conditions for $f(x) f(1-x)$ to be concave
Let $f : [0,1] \to [0,1]$. Function $f$ is decreasing and satisfies $f(0) = 1$. Does anyone know any conditions on $f$ that ensure that the function
$$g(x) = f(x) f(1-x)$$
is concave on the interval $[0,1]$? Of course, the second derivative of $g$ being nonnegative is such a condition, but perhaps there is something more intuitive.

Could you state your result concerning the case where $f$ is two times differentiable ?

@julio_es_sui_glace: you may assume that $f$ is twice differentiable. But I'd be interested in both cases.

I do not have a complete answer but I have two ideas:
First, notice that if $f$ is convex (or concave) then so is $x \mapsto f(1-x)$. You can prove this using the standard definitions (without the use of derivatives). However, notice that we cannot make any statements about the product of two convex/concave functions. Thus, I think that a simple assumption on the convexity/concavity of $f$ will not do the job.
Secondly, assume that $f \in C^2([0,1])$, hence
$$
g''(x) = f''(x)f(1-x) -f'(x)f'(1-x) - f'(x) f'(1-x) + f(x) f''(1-x).
$$
This relation may be helpful since the first and last term on the r.h.s are either both positive or negative (if $f$ is strictly convex or concave).

Apparently, some people consider this to be a bad answer. Please add some information in comments.

The expression for $g''$ may be simplified to $g''(x)=f''(x)f(1-x)-2f'(x)f'(1-x)+f(x)f''(1-x)$. Then, it can be seen that $g$ is concave if $f$ is concave and $\ge 0$ on [0,1].
